# Image matching using intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration

Currently I have a dataset of images (sequence of frames) and I have the intrinsic camera calibration matrix. Also, for each image I have the extrinsic parameters (rotation and traslation).

I would like to know if it is possible use that parameters to find the correct pixel correspondences between each pair of images.

I found the relationship traslation (t) and rotation (R) with each correspondence point between two different perspectives.

[image]

I guess that using the image above, it is only necessary to fix a "x" point (in homogeneous coordinates) and solve the equation system for "x'", but I do not know what operation is using (notations). If someone know how to do it using matlab, I hope some help.

Also, if there is another way to discover the matching using the same information I hope the help of someone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, this information is not enough to find point correspondences between the frames. I will first explain what I think that you can do with the given information, and then we'll see why it's impossible to get pixel to pixel matches from the Essential alone.

- **What you can do.** For a point `m`, you can find the line on the other image where `m'` lies, by using the Fundamental matrix. Let's assume that the `X` and `X'` you give in your question are (respectively) projected to `m` and `m'`, *i.e.*

  ```
  //K denotes the intrinsics matrix
  m=KX
  m'=KX'
  ```

  Starting with your equation, we have:

  ```
   X^{T}EX'=0  ==>  m^T K^{-T} E K^{-1} m'
  ```

  The matrix `K^{-T} E K^{-1}` , that we will note `F`, is known as the Fundamental matrix, and now you have a constraint between 2d points in the image plane:

  ```
   m^TFm'=0
  ```

  Note that `m` and `m'` are 3d vectors expressed in homogeneous coordinates. The interesting thing to notice here, is that `Fm'` is the line on which `m` lies on the first image (since the constraint given above is nothing but the dot product between `m` and `Fm'`). Similarly, `m^TF` is the line on the other image in which `m'` is expected to lie. So, what you can do to find a match for `m`, is to search in a neighborhood of `Fm'`.
- **Why you can't get pixel to pixel matching.** Let's look at   what the constraint `xEx'=0` means from an intuitive point of view. Basically, what it says is that we expect `x`, `x'` and the baseline `T` to be coplanar. Assume that you fix `x`, and that you look for points that satisfy `xEx'=0`. Then while the `x'` in you figure satisfies this constraint, every point `n` (reprojected from `y`) such as the one is the figure below will also be a good candidate:

  [image]

  which indicates that the correct match depends on your estimation of the depth of `x`, which you don't have.

Comment: what If I have the depth ? Can you describe the formulas to get the point to point estimation ? (the depth is known from a third party application assume)